# FindControl and FindControlRecursive returning null for Label in Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Newbie trying to use FindControl and/or FindControlRecursive to get the value of a label in a FormView, however, keep getting the NULL value. The button click is being executed after the FormView is executed (the values in the FormView can be seen on the executed web page so it seems like the data has been bound?). Regardless of using FindControl or FindControlRecursive, can't find the value of the Label control.

Here is the .aspx page (abridged):

```
 <asp:FormView ID="frmOpportunity" runat="server" BackColor="#EAEAEA" BorderColor="Black"     BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="OpportunityID" DataSourceID="sds_OpportunitiesFiltered" EnableModelValidation="True" Style="text-align: left" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="frmOpportunity_PageIndexChanging" OnDataBound="frmOpportunity_PreRender">

                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <table style="border: solid; color: orange;">
                               <tr>
                                  <td rowspan="22" valign="top">
                                        <strong><span class="auto-style11">Subject:</span></strong><br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="False" Height="30px" Text='<%# Eval("Subject") %>' Width="800px"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <strong>Internal:</strong><br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="OpportunityLabel" runat="server" BackColor="White" Text='<%# Bind("Opportunity") %>' Width="800px" />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <strong>Artists:</strong><br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="Specification" runat="server" BackColor="White" Text='<%# Bind("Specification") %>' Width="800px" />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />


                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                          </table>
                      </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:FormView>
```

Here is the code behind (Option 1 - FindControlRecursive):

```
 public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
     {
         if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

         foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
         {
             Control controlToReturn =
                 FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
             if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
         }
         return null;
     }

  protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            Label eSubject = (Label)FindControlRecursive(frmOpportunity,"Label2");
            mail.Subject = eSubject.Text; 
     }
```

In this version eSubject returns NULL.

Here is the code behind (Option 2 - FindControl):

```
 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
                 Label eSubject = (Label)frmOpportunity.FindControl("Label2");
                 mail.Subject = eSubject.Text; 
          }
```

In this version eSubject returns NULL.

Also tried to make sure the FormView was in the right mode and created the following which was run in the FormView on both PreRender and OnDataBound and in both cases created an exception error because the FindControl returned NULL.

```
 protected void frmOpportunity_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (frmOpportunity.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
         {
             Label ProductNameTextBox = frmOpportunity.FindControl("OpportunityLabel") as Label;
             string test = ProductNameTextBox.Text;

         }
     }
```

Comment: If controls are inside ItemTemplate then you cannot fetch them directly as you have tried. You need to get the current item and then fetch the control from the selected Item.

Comment: @Narendra I modified the original post. Checking the mode of the FormView did not change the results of the FindControl which returned NULL.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839761/controls-in-itemtemplate-cant-be-called-in-code-behind   or
http://forums.asp.net/t/1469854.aspx?Button+control+inside+gridview+itemtemplate+how+to+access+it+in+code+behind+

Also I wornder why you are using "ItemTemplate"??

Comment: I am using ItemTemplate because I am not trying to manipulate the data on the page. I am trying to grab the value of the label in the item template, to convert it to string and then incorporate that string into an email the page will send. I just need to get the value from the label into a string format. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: I think I found the issue. The page I am working on was imported from another solution and has had a lot of errors. I thought I caught them all but I think there is an error somewhere that is precluding the FindControl from working. I recreated the functionality on a new page and was able to find the label using FindControl with no problems. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user2956257 I know it has been some time, but would you mind providing a solution to the problem, or explaining what exactly you found? I have the same issue. And there are no errors anywhere. Other than the mentioned one on this page.